# From an object, extract properties with names matching a test

Tags: javascript, object, idioms

I have a props object which will contain an unknown set of properties, some of which I want to extract based on their prefix. I have something that works (great!) but it seems long-winded, and I want to know if there's a more idiomatic way of doing it?

```js
const props = {
  bingo: 1,
  bongo: 2,
  mingo: 3,
  bango: 4
}
const bFields = {}
Object.keys(props).filter(k => (k.startsWith('b'))).forEach(k => (
  bFields[k] = props[k]
))

console.log(props)
console.log(bFields)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const props = {
  bingo: 1,
  bongo: 2,
  mingo: 3,
  bango: 4
}
const bFields = Object.keys(props).reduce((acc, prop) => {
  if (prop.startsWith('b')) {
    acc[prop] = props[prop]
  }

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(props);
console.log(bFields);
```

Comment: I like this one - seems to be lest 'side-effecty', (if only that were a word ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

> How about this **one-liner**

```js
let props = {bingo:1,bongo:2,mingo:3,bango:4}, filteredProps = {};
Object.keys(props).forEach(x => x.startsWith('b') ? filteredProps[x] = props[x] : '');

console.log(filteredProps);
```

Comment: That's a sneaky use of `filteredProps[x] = props[x]` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`

```js
const props = {"bingo":1,"bongo":2,"mingo":3,"bango":4}
const bFields = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).filter(([k])=>k.toLowerCase().startsWith('b')))
console.log(bFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the goal "More understandable by someone that doesn't code" I don't know if it was that but here is the code.

```js
const props = {
  bingo: 1,
  bongo: 2,
  mingo: 3,
  bango: 4
}
const bFields = {};
function matchByStart (key, idx, all) {
  if (key.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) bFields[key] = props[key];
}
Object.keys(props).map(matchByStart);
console.log(bFields);
```

Hope it helps!

`edit: Also I put the method toLowerCase()!`